# How i can use DropDown from Materialize css in React

Tags: reactjs, materialize

How can I use DropDown from Materialize css in React component?
When I click on the button, there is no dropdown content 
My code below:

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import 'materialize-css';

export default class extends Component{
      openDropDown(){
          $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
                  inDuration: 300,
                  outDuration: 225,
                  constrainWidth: false, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
                  hover: true, // Activate on hover
                  gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
                  belowOrigin: false, // Displays dropdown below the button
                  alignment: 'left', // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
                  stopPropagation: false // Stops event propagation
              }
          );
      }
      render(){
        return(
            <div className="input-field col s12">
                <a className='dropdown-button btn' data-activates='dropdown1' onClick={()=> this.openDropDown} >Drop Me!</a>
                <ul classID='dropdown1' className='dropdown-content'>
                    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
                    <li className="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!"><i className="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!"><i className="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use JQuery with React and MaterializeCSS in order to initialise components.

What you need to do is correctly import `M` and initialise the dropdown inside `componentDidMount()`. There are two ways to do this;

You can simply use AutoInit().

```
M.AutoInit();
```

Or, as you're also passing options to initialise, you'd want to use:

```
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
M.Dropdown.init(elems, {inDuration: 300, outDuration: 225});
```

My IDE seems to pick up that `Downdown` doesn't exist on `M`, however, the code runs fine in the browser.

An example with the above:

```
import M from 'materialize-css';  

class Foo extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
        M.Dropdown.init(elems, {inDuration: 300, outDuration: 225});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="input-field col s12">
                <a className='dropdown-button btn' data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>
                <ul id='dropdown1' className='dropdown-content'>
                  <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
                  <li className="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#!"><i className="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#!"><i className="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
export default Foo;
```

Check out [Materialize Dropdowns](https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html) to see their docs on initialisation without JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Better way with useRef:

```
import M from 'materialize-css';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

type Props = {};

// TODO dynamically load the materialize-css dependency
export const SettingsMenuDropDown = (_props: Props) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const elem = ref.current;
    M.Dropdown.init(elem, { inDuration: 300, outDuration: 225 });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <a
        ref={ref}
        className="setting-menu dropdown-trigger matelializecss-default-setting-initial"
        data-target="dropdown-setting-menu"
      />
        
      <ul
        className="dropdown-content default-pattern"
        id="dropdown-setting-menu"
      >        
        <li>
          <Link href={'/settings'}>Settings</Link>
        </li>            
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

There's an import for materialize, (it's react compatible materialize module, which makes work super easy!) I would suggest using it, rather than making it yourself.

Though the docs are yet to complete, you can refer to them!
Getting started with materialize for react : https://react-materialize.github.io/#/

Materialize DropDown here : https://react-materialize.github.io/#/dropdown

Good going!

Comment: This is not an import. It's a package. react-materialize contains only subset of Materialize components which would need to be maintained as new features are released by the Materialize team. 
I'm not saying don't use the package, I'm sure it has some advantages and ease of use; just something to think about before moving a whole project over!

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's question.